# Select some text in an input field, but not all, when it is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input, field

If I have a text field like `<input type="text" name="summary" value="Summary: This is a test.">`, is it possible to make it so that when the user clicks on the field, or uses Tab to reach it, that rather than select all of the text, only part of it is selected?

In this case, I'd like the `This is a test` part to be selected, so the user can immediately start typing to replace it with what they want.

Is this possible with JavaScript, and if necessary, some type of hack to make it work?

Unfortunately, I am quite limited by what other options I have in this case; typically, alternatives would be to place the `Summary:` outside the text box, for instance, so it can't be edited.

Comment: Do you just need selection, or do you need the also make the user not be able to change the "Summary:" part?

Comment: No, just selection is fine. The user is allowed to change the "Summary" portion. Although I'd be interested to see what solution you can come up with to keep the "Summary" portion uneditable! (Unless it is simply by keeping that portion out of the text box.)

Comment: Gary this is not possible... if you disable your input, you wont be able to edit any part of your text... you cant disable only a part of the text

Comment: Okay thanks, that is what I figured anyway. It isn't what my goal is at the moment, but I was merely curious to see if that is even possible.

Comment: @Thiago To say something is not possible is being too literal, I think it's quite possible to emulate behavior that is "close enough"

Comment: I'm curious - what is your end goal with this? Perhaps there's a better solution that could accomplish what you need.

Comment: Basically I'm just placing a default summary, and allowing the user to edit it if they want. So automatically selecting the default summary would allow the user to start typing immediately; otherwise they can just Tab out to not change it.

Comment: Right - I understand that. What I'm wondering is *why* you need this. Does the "Summary:" bit need to be sent to the server as is? Or is this a curiosity?

Comment: Well the "Summary:" in this question is just a placeholder/example. I will have other different types of text there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57946/discussion-between-jdphenix-and-gary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes man it is possible... here I have an example that selects a part of your fields text...

```
$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};

$('input').selectRange(6,15);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WpqsN/1972/

so you can use it like this:

```
$('input').click(function(){
    $('input').selectRange(6,15);
});
```

or

```
$('input').one('click',function(){
    $('input').selectRange(6,15);
});
```

to run only on FIRST click

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't seem to be working for me either. I'm using the latest Firefox. Here is what actually seems to be happening: If I click on the word "beautiful" itself, then for a split second, the entire word is selected, then it is no longer selected. If I click anywhere else in the box, then nothing special happens.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that this only works on the first click. After that, it seems like the code never activates anymore (until a page load).

Comment: yes, it really was not working correct.... but now I edited it... try it... its working!!

Comment: `var selFocus = function() { console.log("a");
    var txt = $(this);
    $(this).off("focus.fcs").blur();
    window.setTimeout( function(){ txt.selectRange(6,15).on("focus.fcs", selFocus);; },10);
};
`

Comment: Yes it works now! Now, is it possible to only make this work on the FIRST focus, and not subsequent ones? I'm sure I can get it to do that on my own, but I might as well ask.

Comment: yes, I edited the code.... it only runs on FIRST focus http://jsfiddle.net/WpqsN/1973/

Comment: Okay thanks. I added a `<textarea>` before the field, then tabbed to the input field, but it doesn't seem to select the specified text like it does when clicking, unfortunately. Would simply adding a `.focus()` do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Alright - this attempts creates an "uneditable" field name inside the `<input>`'s value. The reason it attempts but isn't completely successful is because it actually is editable, but if the user changes the field name, it tries to recover the value and restore the field name.

Here's the Javascript:

```
var Fields = {
  Seperator:":"
}

Fields.copyFieldName = function (element) {
  if (element.dataset.fieldname) {
    var seperatorIndex = Fields.findSeperator(element); 
    if (element.value.substring(0, seperatorIndex) !== element.dataset.fieldname) {
      var oldValue = element.value.substring(seperatorIndex + 1, element.value.length)
      element.value = element.dataset.fieldname + Fields.Seperator + oldValue;
    }
  }
};

Fields.findSeperator = function (element) {
  return element.value.indexOf(Fields.Seperator); 
}; 

Fields.selectInputValue = function (element) {
  if (element.type === "text") {
    if (element.setSelectionRange) {
      element.setSelectionRange(
        Fields.findSeperator(element) + 1, 
        element.value.length
      );
    } else if (element.createTextRange) {
      var range = element.createTextRange();
      range.moveStart("character", Fields.findSeperator(element) + 1);
      range.moveEnd("character", element.value.length);
      range.select();
    }
  }
};


$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[data-fieldname]").each(function (index, element) {
    Fields.copyFieldName(element); 

    $(element).click(function () {
      Fields.copyFieldName(element);
      Fields.selectInputValue(this);
    });

    $(element).focusin(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      Fields.copyFieldName(element);
      Fields.selectInputValue(this);
    }); 
  });
});
```

And HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="extra1" value="an extra field" />
<input type="text" name="summary" value="this is a test" data-fieldname="Summary" />
<input type="text" name="extra2" value="an extra field" />
```

Please note, I made a small modification to you field example. I use a `data-*` attribute to store the name of the field.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tFRD4/4/

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I type in the "Summary:" field, the "Summary:" portion is indeed uneditable, but I can only type up to 1 character in that field. So it ends up looking like "Summary: a" and any other characters I type replace the last character, so it ends up like "Summary: b", etc.

Comment: @Gary oops, updated with the fix. I instead bound to focus and prevented it's default (if you don't do this, most browsers will select all the text in the field)

Comment: It still seems to be doing it, at least in the Fiddle.

Comment: new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tFRD4/4/ , I apologize, the jsFiddle-ness is clearly not strong with this one, hehe :)